# What is the use case for negative slicing and indexing in lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Referring to [30 Python Language features](http://sahandsaba.com/thirty-python-language-features-and-tricks-you-may-not-know.html)

**1.6   List slices with negative indexing:**

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a[-4:-2]
[7, 8]
```

- Where is negative slicing and indexing most commonly used?
- Is there a case where it is even indispensable so that it must exist as a language feature?

Comment: Would you rather write `a[len(a)-4:len(a)-2]`?

Comment: It provides clearer syntax for lists that don't have a fixed length and from which you want the last elements.

Comment: @vaultah, no I'd rather write a[7:8].. oops [7:9]

Comment: I don't think this is more common that positive slicing, e.g. `a[7:9]`

Comment: @goldcode yeah, okay. What if you don't know the length of `a` beforehand or it's large?

Comment: returning the nth element from the right-hand side of the list (as opposed to the usual left-hand side),a negative number should be used as an index

Comment: @vaultah, so back to my question, where would I commonly require to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One very common scenario where a negative attribute of the slice is handy is reversing of the sequence, i.e:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a[::-1]
```

where the `slice` has a negative `step` value.

Another, equally common, is grabbing the *last element* of a sequence with `a[-1]`. Without negative indexing you'd resort to ugly `a[len(a)-1]` code; now you can simply let Python add the `len` to the value behind the scenes without worrying.

This convenience that Python kindly offers has been around since at least version `1.4` (oldest docs I have generally found); I am doubtful of this being "indispensable" someplace, it's just one of the many things that makes Python a bit friendlier.

Comment: Just thought I'd add to this that you can also count from the end with 0-based indexing using the `~` operator, which gives the compliment of an integer. So the last element of a list is `a[~0]`, second last is `a[~1]`, etc.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore sure, though, I think we all agree that using the invert operator is just a horrible alternative :-)

Comment: Not sure I'd agree it's horrible, it has its uses. Like the standard loop-based palindrome check looks nicer as `string[i] == string[~i]` rather than `string[i] == string[-i-1]`.

Comment: @CurtisLusmore of course; horrible in the context of getting the last element from a sequence, not horrible in general.